# tabla en html que no muestran todos los resultados de un select

Tags: java, html, web

BUenas amigos tengo una aplicacion web con una tabla a la cual al momento de presionar el boton "buscar" tomando como valor lo elegido en el combobox por defecto '0'..debe mostrarme todas las tiendas existentes en la BD, lo probe en toadOracle y funciona perfectamente, me muestran todos los resultados, pero en mi aplicacion web solo me muestra un resultado,pase el query modificado a mi proyecto en java EE tal cual y probe que de hecho este capturando el '0' y si lo hace, que podre estar haciendo mal, a continuacion el query en java

```
String stringQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT * " + "FROM ( "
            + "SELECT tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal, "
            + "tmp_barra_primaria.descripcionCorta, "
            + "tmp_barra_primaria.descripcionLarga, " + "im.dept, "
            + "vi.vat_rate, " + "rfr2.selling_retail, "
            + "TO_CHAR(rpile.detail_start_date,'yyyymmdd'), " + "TO_CHAR(rpile.detail_end_date,'yyyymmdd'), "
            + "rpile.promo_comp_id, " + "rpile.promo_id, "
            + "DECODE(uil.uda_value, " + "'0', " + "'Normal', " + "'4', "
            + "'Pesable', " + "'7', " + "'Procesado') estado, "
            + "rfr2.simple_promo_retail,null,im.standard_uom,MFG_REC_RETAIL  " + "FROM item_master       im, "
            + "vat_item          vi, " + "store             s, "
            + "uda_item_lov      uil, " + "rpm_future_retail rfr2, " +

            "(SELECT decode(im.item_number_type, " + "'ITEM', "
            + "im.item, " + "im.item_parent) codigoPrincipal, "
            + "im.item_desc descripcionLarga, "
            + "im.short_desc descripcionCorta " + "FROM item_master im "
            + "WHERE im.item = ?1) tmp_barra_primaria " +

            "LEFT OUTER JOIN(item_loc il) "
            + "ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = il.item AND "
            + "il.loc = DECODE(?2,'0',il.loc,?2)) " +
            "LEFT OUTER JOIN(rpm_future_retail rfr) "
            + "ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rfr.item AND "
            + "rfr.location = DECODE(?2,'0',rfr.location,?2) AND "
            + "TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= "
            + "TO_DATE(rfr.action_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND "
            + "(to_date(sysdate) - to_date(rfr.action_date)) >= 0) "
            + "LEFT OUTER JOIN(rpm_promo_item_loc_expl rpile) "
            + "ON (tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal = rpile.item AND "
            + "rpile.location = DECODE(?2,'0',rpile.location,?2) AND "
            + "TO_DATE(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY') between "
            + "TO_DATE(rpile.detail_start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND "
            + "to_date(rpile.detail_end_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')) " +

            "WHERE im.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal "
            + "AND VI.VAT_TYPE IN ('R', 'B')"
            + "AND vi.item = im.item " + "AND s.store = DECODE(?2,'0',s.store,?2) "
            + "AND s.vat_region = vi.vat_region "
            + "AND uil.item = im.item " + "AND uil.uda_id = 3 "
            + "AND rfr2.item = tmp_barra_primaria.codigoPrincipal "
            + "AND rfr2.location = DECODE(?2,'0',rfr2.location,?2) " +

            "AND (to_date(SYSDATE) - to_date(rfr2.action_date)) >= 0)";
```

en el decode si selecciona una tienda por ejemplo la numero 1 me muestra solo esa, a cambio si en el combobox selecciono "todas" que su indice es '0' deberia de mostrarme en la tabla todas las tiendas y solo me muestra una

aca el codigo de la tabla

```
jQuery("#tablaProductos")
                        .jqGrid(
                        {
                            //  url:'tabla_producto.html',
                            datatype: "json",
                            height: 190,
                            width: 865,
                            colNames: [ 'Ip',
                                'Sistema',
                                'NumeroSucursal',
                                'Sucursal',
                                'Código Principal',
                                'Descripción Corta',
                                'Precio',
                                'Precio Promoción',
                                'PV Justo'],
                            colModel: [
                                {
                                    name: 'ip',
                                    index: 'ip',
                                    width: 50,
                                    align: "center",
                                    hidden: true,
                                    sortable: false

                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'sistema',
                                    index: 'sistema',
                                    width: 50,
                                    align: "center",
                                    hidden: true,
                                    sortable: false

                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'numeroSucursal',
                                    index: 'numeroSucursal',
                                    width: 50,
                                    align: "center",
                                    hidden: true,
                                    sortable: false

                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'sucursal',
                                    index: 'sucursal',
                                    width: 50,
                                    align: "center",
                                    sortable: false

                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'codigoPrincipal',
                                    index: 'codigoPrincipal',
                                    width: 50,
                                    align: "center",
                                    sortable: false

                                }
                                ,
                                {
                                    name: 'descripcionCorta',
                                    index: 'descripcionCorta',
                                    width: 70,
                                    align: "center",
                                    sortable: false

                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'precio',
                                    index: 'precio',
                                    width: 35,
                                    align: "center",
                                    sortable: false

                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'precioPromocion',
                                    index: 'precioPromocion',
                                    width: 35,
                                    align: "center",
                                    sortable: false

                                },
                                {
                                    name: 'pvJusto',
                                    index: 'pvJusto',
                                    width: 35,
                                    align: "center",
                                    sortable: false

                                },
                            ],
                            rowNum: 5,
                            rowList: [ 8, 10, 20, 30 ],
                            pager: '#plist4',
                            sortname: 'sucursal',
                            jsonReader: {
                                repeatitems: false,
                                id: "0"
                            },
                            recordpos: 'left',
                            multiselect: true,
                            multiboxonly: true,

                            viewrecords: true,
                            sortorder: "desc",
                            toolbar: [ true, "top" ],

                            subGrid: true,
                            caption: "Información Productos RMS",

                            afterInsertRow: function (ids, aData) {
                                jQuery("#tablaProductoRms")
                                        .jqGrid(
                                        'setCell',
                                        ids,
                                        'precio',
                                        '',
                                        {
                                            color: 'red'

                                        });
                                jQuery("#tablaProductoRms")
                                        .jqGrid(
                                        'setCell',
                                        ids,
                                        'precioPromocion',
                                        '',
                                        {
                                            color: 'red'
                                        });
                            },
                            onSelectRow: function (id) {


                                jQuery('#tablaProductoRms').jqGrid('editRow', id, true);

                            },

                            ondblClickRow: function (ids) {
                                $("#tablaProductos2").jqGrid(
                                        'setGridState',
                                        'visible');
                                $("#loading").show();
                                //  $("#tablaProductoControlador").jqGrid('setGridState','visible');
                                var fila = jQuery(
                                        "#tablaProductos")
                                        .getRowData(ids);
```

espéro puedan orientarme en que podria estar haciendo mal, no se si la tabla tendra alguna propiedad que le permita solo mostrar un resultado por consulta, espero su ayuda gracias

el llena la tabla mediantes este metodo Informacionproducto()

..aca esta

```
function informacionProducto() {
        $("#loading");
        var formulario = $('#formularioBusqueda');

        if (document.formularioBusqueda.radio2.checked) {
            var x = 0;
            $
                    .post(
                    'ConsultasRms/tabla_consultaProductoPromocion.html',
                    formulario.serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        $("#loading").hide();
                        if (data.rows[0].length == 0 && data.rows[1].length == 0) {
                            $("#dialog-NoDataPromocion").dialog("open");
                        }


                        else {
                            //borramos el contenido de los option del select
                            //$("#comboboxSucursales").html("");
                            //recorremos todas las filas del resultado del proceso que obtenemos en Json


                            comboSucursales = document.getElementById('comboboxSucursales');
                            sucursalConsulta = comboSucursales.options[comboSucursales.selectedIndex].text;

                            var listaProductoActivo = data.rows[0];
                            for (x = 0; x < listaProductoActivo.length; x++) {


                                var datarow = {
                                    sucursal: sucursalConsulta,
                                    numeroSucursal:comboSucursales.options[comboSucursales.selectedIndex].value,
                                    ip: ipControlador,
                                    sistema: tipoSucursal,
                                    codigoPrincipal: listaProductoActivo[x].codigoPrincipal,
                                    descripcionCorta: listaProductoActivo[x].descripcionCorta,
                                    precio: listaProductoActivo[x].precio,
                                    precioPromocion: listaProductoActivo[x].precioPromocion,
                                    pvJusto: listaProductoActivo[x].pvJusto,
                                    statusProducto: listaProductoActivo[x].statusProducto


                                };
                                datarowRmsDetalle[cont] = {
                                    descripcionLarga: listaProductoActivo[x].descripcionLarga,
                                    iva: listaProductoActivo[x].iva,
                                    estado: listaProductoActivo[x].estado,
                                    departamento: listaProductoActivo[x].departamento,
                                    codigoComponente: listaProductoActivo[x].codigoComponente,
                                    codigoPromocion: listaProductoActivo[x].codigoPromocion,
                                    fechaInicioPromocion: listaProductoActivo[x].fechaInicioPromocion,
                                    fechaFinPromocion: listaProductoActivo[x].fechaFinPromocion

                                };


                                var su = jQuery("#tablaProductoRms")
                                        .jqGrid('addRowData', cont,
                                        datarow);

                                cont++;
                            }
```

Comment: cuantos resultados devuelve tu consulta, y cuantos puedes ver en tu tabla?

Comment: cuando hago la prueba en toad, me devuelve 54 resultados, es decir las 54 tiendas, pero cuando pruebo la aplicacion en el navegador en mi tabla solo devuelve 1 resultado no muestra todos

Comment: @Jdeveloper, el codigo JS esta incompleto. No veo como es que cargas los datos. La tabla ya existe con todos los resultado y luego creas la jqGrid?

Comment: en la edicion agregue el metodo o funcion que realiza el llenado de la tabla, la tabla esta creada y mediante esa consulta sucursal + el codigo del producto y al presionar buscar muestra los resultados en la tabla, cuando selecciono 'todas' deberia mostrarme todas las tiendas y solo muestra una amigo Marcos Gallardo

Comment: y cual es el registro que te muestra en tu jqGrid? el primero o ultimo registro?

Comment: en la base de datos hay 45 registros, y solo muestra uno amigo, el llena sus campos pero muestra solo un registro